# How can I bump line-height with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In the jsfiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/gQqLs/7/ , I'd like to bump the line height for a div each time a button is selected, the way you can increase padding:

```
        $('#box1') .css('padding-top', "+=5" );  // works
//      $('#box1') .css('line-height', "+=5" );  // does not work
```

You can see in the jsfiddle that I tried to brute-force my way through, but even at line 10 I'm not done because it looks like lineHeight still has to go back to a string to work. There has to be a better way to do this.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The `line-height` bumping from your fiddle works fine in Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116 m. Though it is a little confusing what exactly you want. Do you want to change the line height for each line in a particular `div` or do you want to add padding to the top of it?

Comment: For me the line-height line doesn't work in Chrome either. It does what Firefox does, which is execute the +=5 by turning 20px, the current line-height, into 205px.  Sorry for the confusion with the padding line.  I don't want to do anything with padding.  I just showed the padding line as an example of how I hoped the line-height bump would work.

Comment: This makes sense Steve. I have observed the issue you mentioned and I can see that there is clearly something going wrong. I believe it is either a bug that has been treated in browsers other than Chrome; it could also be an intentionally undefined functionality and thus has not been patched in Chrome. But the resolution seems to be that you need to specify the line height explicitly and that it does not support incrementing by anything other than percentage. In my tests on Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m, the `+= 5` was adding 5%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the following works (http://jsfiddle.net/stas_sl/LkueJ/3/):

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#bump').click(function() {
        newLineHeight = parseInt($('#box1').css('line-height'))+5+'px';
        $('#box1') .css('padding-top', "+=5" );
        $('#box1') .css('line-height', newLineHeight);
    });
});
```